# Remove +0Is from Root function

Tags: equation-solving, complex, physics, eigenvalues

I'm trying to find the zeros of the eigenvalues (functions of $k_x$) of a self-adjoint $4\times4$ matrix H:

```
H = {{kx^2 + a kx + B, 0, I a kx, 
    del}, {0, -kx^2 + a kx - B, -del, -I a kx}, {-I a kx, -del, 
    kx^2 - a kx - B, 0}, {del, I a kx, 0, -kx^2 - a kx + B}};
B = 1;
a = 0.5;
del = 0.02;
evals = Eigenvalues[H]
solns = Table[NSolve[evals[[ii]] == 0, kx, Reals], {ii, 4}]
```

My eigenvalues are all real, but when mathematica calculates them, because of the complex entries in the off-diagonals, it produces a +0I inside the root on some of the coefficients. This causes a problem when I try to solve restricting the domain to the reals:

```
Solve::nddc: The system contains a nonreal constant 0.128451 +0. I. With the domain specified, all constants should be real.
```

I have tried using `Re` which doesn't work, and `Chop` which completely breaks the output when applied to the smaller numbers in the full code (I've tried multiplying by a constant and dividing afterwards). `ToRadicals` leads to an extremely large expression which NSolve struggles to evaluate (`FullSimplify` on this gives similar problems). How do I remove the +0I efficiently?

Comment: Does `expr /. I -> 0` work?

Comment: Provide definition of `H` so that we can reproduce the problem

Comment: @MariusLadegårdMeyer Nope

Comment: @BobHanlon updated

Comment: Please provide the definition in Mathematica code along with the values of the parameters that are causing the problem.

Comment: @BobHanlon Done, sorry about that. Will try to be more careful in future with giving everything that is needed to reproduce the issue.

Answer (score 2):

```
Clear[H, B, a, del]

H = {{kx^2 + a kx + B, 0, I a kx, 
    del}, {0, -kx^2 + a kx - B, -del, -I a kx}, {-I a kx, -del, 
    kx^2 - a kx - B, 0}, {del, I a kx, 0, -kx^2 - a kx + B}};
B = 1;
a = 0.5;
del = 0.02;
```

Use [`Chop`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Chop.html) in the definition of `evals` to eliminate the complex artifacts (`0. I`).

```
evals = Eigenvalues[H] // Chop;

solns = NSolve[# == 0, kx, Reals] & /@ evals

(* {{}, {{kx -> -1.34174}, {kx -> -0.845824}}, {{kx -> 1.34174}, {kx -> 
    0.845824}}, {}} *)
```

Alternatively, use exact values for the parameters

```
Clear[H, B, a, del]

H = {{kx^2 + a kx + B, 0, I a kx, 
    del}, {0, -kx^2 + a kx - B, -del, -I a kx}, {-I a kx, -del, 
    kx^2 - a kx - B, 0}, {del, I a kx, 0, -kx^2 - a kx + B}};
B = 1;
a = 1/2;
del = 1/50;

evals = Eigenvalues[H];

solns2 = NSolve[# == 0, kx, Reals] & /@ evals

(* {{}, {{kx -> -1.34174}, {kx -> -0.845824}}, {{kx -> 1.34174}, {kx -> 
    0.845824}}, {}} *)

solns == solns2

(* True *)
```